# JSON file error in VSC: Expected comma json(514)

Tags: json

Im having a issue, im doing a discord bot i was putting the dependicies but it apears Expected commajson(514)

```
    {
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "HR0d4s",
  "license": "ISC"
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "13.06.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put a comma after "ISC". So your code should look like this:

```
    {
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "HR0d4s",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "13.06.0"
  }
}
```

Hope this works!